# "unexpected keyword_do_block" when trying to use a block

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, block

This is my program:

```
my_hash.each |w| do
    p "is this right?"
    awesome_print w
    fix = gets
    fix.chop
    if (fix == "N")
        p "Tell me what it should be"
        correction = gets
        w[1] = correction
    end
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
what.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
what.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

does anybody know why I get that error?

here's my_hash:
`{:banana=>:fruit, :pear=>:fruit, :sandal=>:fruit, :panda=>:fruit, :apple=>:fruit}`

I just want to operate on each individual key pair in the conventional Ruby way. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the syntax backward. It should be:

```
my_hash.each do |w|
```

Instead of:

```
my_hash.each |w| do
```

Comment: I knew that, I swear. made a rookie mistake.

Comment: @DavidWest: Well, glad to help. You have no idea how many hours I've spent on these kinds of errors.

Comment: how do I use an enumerator to change the hash in a program like this. I'm changing it around (had to do `chop!` instead of `chop` for instance) but in the end `my_hash` doesn't change.

Comment: Change `each` to `map` and add `Hash[*(the_map_statment_here).flatten]`. Eg: `hash = Hash[*(hash.map {|w| [w[0], w[1]]}.flatten)]`.

Comment: @DavidWest Ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @Linuxios can you join here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual